# MySql stored procedure help! so close

Tags: mysql

Okay i'm on my very last question in this MySQL section of my book.  And it's about stored procedures (D:).  Having a little troubles understanding some logic.  I have the basics of it down and have written many stored procs.  But this one is confusing.

Any and all help would be amazing.

Question:

-- 4.Create a stored procedure named spUpdateStudent that accepts a student name and the
-- next of kin information as parameters. The procedure must insert the next of kin
-- information into the Next of kin table by looking up the student id from the Student table.

My code:

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE `UniversityDB`.`spUpdateStudent`(In  student_first_name VARCHAR(25), next_of_kin varchar(50))
BEGIN 
    SELECT * 
    FROM next_of_kin;
  WHERE student_id = 01234;  -- Example 
  INSERT next_of_kin;
END // 
DELIMITER;
CALL spUpdateStudent();
```

My database name is UniversityDB.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: what is the `--` supposed to be in your text?

Answer (score 0):

You’re almost there!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `UniversityDB`.`spUpdateStudent`(In  p_student_first_name VARCHAR(25), p_next_of_kin varchar(50))
BEGIN
    -- Declare a variable to hold the ID of the student
    DECLARE v_student_id INT;
    -- Get the student ID
    SELECT student.id INTO v_student_id FROM student;
    WHERE student_firstname = p_student_first_name

    -- Now we have the student id lets update the next of kin table
    UPDATE next_of_kin
    SET next_of_kin.name = p_next_of_kin
    WHERE next_of_kin = v_student_id
END //
```

I've used "p_" at the start of parameter names and "v_" at the start of variable names. This isn't (i don't think) any specific standard however I like it as it makes sense when reading where the values come from.